# How to iterate over columns to get row labeled data in Excel?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am writing a Java program in which I want to retrieve data which has row headers. My Excel sheet looks like below:

[image]

I have written a following simple Java code to retrieve values sequentially based on row headers:

```
....
try
    {
    fileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem (inpStrm);

    HSSFWorkbook      workBook = new HSSFWorkbook (fileSystem);
    HSSFSheet         sheet    = workBook.getSheetAt(0);
    int column = 1;
    for(int i = 0;i <=3;i++){

        for(int j = 0;j<=3;j++){
            HSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(j);
            System.out.print(row.getCell(column).getStringCellValue() + "    ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
        column++;
    }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
....
```

And after running code my output comes like below:

```
P1    M    C1    Hyderabad    
P2    M    C2    Pune    
P3    F    C3    Pune    
P4    M    C4    Hyderabad
```

Now is there any easy and feasible way to do the same for large Excel sheets (50 row headers)?

If I use the POGO class having above four properties then how can I get list of objects with values from Excel?

Comment: Just loop over all the rows? I'm not seeing what the problem is with your code?

Comment: @Gagravarr Thanks for your reply :). There is no problem in my code. I am asking if there is any other easy way by which I can achieve the same requirement?

Comment: I'd suggest using `WorkbookFactory` to create your workbook, and `DataFormatter` to turn the cell into a string, but otherwise it looks pretty simple and easy to me!

Comment: You could remove that unused for loop (the one with the `i`). I don't exactly know what you mean by `POGO class`. Did you mean `POJO`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Now is there any easy and feasible way to do the same for large Excel sheets (50 row headers)?

You could use the method [`sheet.getLastRowNum()`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.html#getLastRowNum()) as condition in your for loop to iterate over all rows and the method [`row.getLastCellNum()`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#getLastCellNum()) in a second loop to iterate over all cells in a specific row.

```
for(int rowNumber = 0; rowNumber < sheet.getLastRowNum(); rowNumber++) {
    HSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(rowNumber);

    for(int columnNumber = 0; columnNumber < row.getLastCellNum(); columnNumber++) {
        HSSFCell cell = row.getCell(columnNumber);
        if(cell != null) {
            // do something with the cell
        }
}
```

**Important:** The code above loops first through each column and then through each row.

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
for (Cell cell : sheet.getRow(i )) {

    //your logic
}
```